# Pulling data after sort the table

Tags: sorting, sas

My problem is pulling right variables from data. My data is as below:

```
id   term  grade  number
35   2005   I       0
35   2005   F       1
35   2005   W       2
46   2003   A       0
46   2003   B       1
46   2003   F       2
46   2003   I       3
```

I sorted the table I have and gave number 0-1-2 and so on. This is the example after sorting. What I need  is if the same id's grades are starts with I and F and W. Like id 35. So I need in this table is first three observations id 35.

Comment: Please do not post requests for code like this; at least make some attempt.  This problem is well covered online.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one Proc SQL approach, you can also try 2XDOW:

```
data have;
    input (id   term  grade) (:$8.)  number;
    cards;
35   2005   I       0
35   2005   F       1
35   2005   W       2
46   2003   A       0
46   2003   B       1
46   2003   F       2
46   2003   I       3 
;

proc sql;
    create table want as
        select * from have
            group by id
                having sum(GRADE='I' AND NUMBER=0) >0
                    AND  sum(GRADE='F' AND NUMBER=1) >0
                    AND sum(GRADE='W' AND NUMBER=2) >0
    ;
QUIT;
```

Comment: It doesn't give me right solution. It should be first I and F then W. It doesn't give me on this line

Comment: Please explain how. It should work the way as It works on your sample data. Please give an example how it doesn't work.

Comment: If just the order ist your problem, add an order statement to Haikuos solution (order by number), otherwise his solution is exactly what you want, as far as i understand your post